# Remove newline character from a string?

Tags: string, matlab

I have a string that is like so:

```
"string content here
 "
```

because it is too long to fit on the screen in one line

The string is the name of a file i would like to read, but i always get an error message that the file name wasn't found because it includes the new line character in the string when this obviously isn't in the file name. I cannot rename the file and I have tried the strip function to remove it, but this doesn't work. How can I remove the enter character from my string so I can load my file?

Comment: Is it a string or a character vector? Your words say "string" but example says character vector. What happens if you call `size()` on the variable storing the string/character vector?

Comment: My apologies, i think it is a character vector, I'm very new to Matlab. I get ans =

     1     1

Comment: Then it is a string. If it is a character vector, (indicated by 'text') then each letter is an entry into a vector ('text' is 4 long). If it is a string, it is just 1 element (indicated by "text").

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`strip`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strip.html) to remove any trailing whitespace from a string.

```
>> text = "hello" + newline; %Create test string.
>> disp(text)
hello

>> text_stripped = strip(text);
>> disp(text_stripped)
hello
>>
```

In the above ">>" has been included to better present the removal of the whitespace in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Consider replacing the newline character with nothing using `strrep`. [Link](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html)

As an example:

```
s = sprintf('abc\ndef')     % Create a string s with a newline character in the middle
s = strrep(s, newline, '')  % Replace newline with nothing
```

Alternatively, you could use [regular expressions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) if there are several characters causing you issues.

Alternatively, you could use [strip](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strip.html) if you know the newline always occurs at the beginning or end.

Comment: Your string is not a string. `s` is a character array. However, `strrep` obviously also works for strings, so your answer is perfectly valid.